# Unanticipated error when using a cond statement

Tags: common-lisp

New to common lisp and having a very rookie problem. My function of one variable is supposed to return the absolute of of the entered variable. It works for when the variable is above or equal to 0 but not below, I suspect this is due to the cond function but i'm not sure.

I have tried the code with brackets and without but cannot see why it is failing. I know this is not the best way of solving this problem but i am just trying to get used to the cond statement at this stage.

```
     (defun abs-x (x)
       (cond ((> x 0) x)
             ((= x 0) 0)
             ((< x 0) (-x))))
```

The error message when a variable below 0 is entered is '-X is undefined.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
    (- x)
;     ^
;     |
;  The space
;  is important.
```

instead of `(-x)`.

That's because `-` is a valid character in an identifier, so `-x` is a valid function name. With the space between `-` and `x`, though, it calls the function `-` which takes one or more arguments.

Comment: Thanks so much. Knew it would be something simple1

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
 (defun abs-x (x)
   (cond ((> x 0) x)
         (t (- x))))
```

Reduced number of checkings using the fact that `(- 0)` also evaluates to`0`.

Instead of `<=` for the last check, use the simpler `t` - the `else` in common lisp `cond` clauses.

With `if` this would be:

```
(defun abs-x (x)
  (if (> x 0)
      x
      (- x)))
```